# How to round decimal place up?

Tags: perl

I'm using the sprintf and printf function to round a decimal number, rounding down if hundredth position is less than 5, rounding up if hundredth position is greater than 5.

```
my $a = 1.12;
my $b = sprintf("%.1f", $a);
print "Unrounded: $a\nRounded: $b\n";
printf "Unrounded: $a\nRounded: %.1f\n", $a;
```

Is there a way to round up the decimal place up (e.g., `$b = 1.2`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ceil` function from the core `POSIX` module to round up to the next integer. Factor your value by a power of ten before and after the operation to round up to a given number of decimal places

Also, don't use identifiers `$a` and `$b`; they are reserved for use by the `sort` built-in operator

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use POSIX 'ceil';

my $aa = 1.12;
print "Unrounded:  $aa\n";

my $bb = sprintf("%.1f", $aa);
print "Rounded:    $bb\n";

my $cc = ceil($aa * 10) / 10;
print "Rounded up: $cc\n";
```

#### output

```
Unrounded:  1.12
Rounded:    1.1
Rounded up: 1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nhimult()` function from the `Math::Round` library

> nhimult TARGET, LIST
>
> Returns the next higher multiple of the number(s) in LIST. TARGET must be positive. In scalar context, returns a single value; in list context, returns a list of values. Numbers that are between two multiples of the target will be adjusted to the nearest multiples of LIST that are algebraically higher. For example:

just do `nhimult(0.1, $a)` as

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Math::Round qw( :all );
my $a = 1.12;
my $b = sprintf("%.1f", $a);
print "Unrounded: $a\nRounded: $b\n";
printf "Unrounded: $a\nRounded: %.1f\n", $a;
printf "Unrounded: $a\nRounded: %.1f\n", $a;    
printf "Next higher multiple of $a: %.1f\n",  nhimult(0.1, $a);
```

produces

```
Unrounded: 1.12
Rounded: 1.1
Unrounded: 1.12
Rounded: 1.1
Unrounded: 1.12
Rounded: 1.1
Next higher multiple of 1.12, 1.2
```

You can get the [Math::Round](http://search.cpan.org/%7Egrommel/Math-Round-0.07/Round.pm) by doing

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Math::Round'
```

and import all the functions `qw(:all)`.